# any information about a sum of the totient function weighted geometrically

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, complex-geometry

I came across this function while investigating the spokes of the mandelbrot set.  It is known that if you zoom into the tip of a spoke on the mandelbrot set then start zooming into a minibrot, you will see spokes first with 1-way rotational symmetry, then with 2 way rotational symmetry, then with 4 way rotational symmetry, and so on with 2^nth way rotational symmetry.  I decided to look into how exactly these spokes connect to the minibrot.

For example, the first spoke always goes into the cusp of the minibrot, the spoke that appears at the start of 2-way symmetry comes from the needle of the minibrot, the 2 spokes that appear at the start of 4-way symmetry connect to minibrot spokes that come from the 2 bulbs on the minibrot's cardioid with a period 3 times that of the cardioid of the minibrot, 2 of the 4 bulbs that appear at the start of 8-way symmetry come from spokes of the 2 bulbs on the cardioid of the minibrot with a period 4 times that of the cardioid, while the other 2 will come from spokes on the 2 bulbs of the main disk of the minibrot with a period 3 times that of the main disk of the minibrot, or 6 times the period of the main cardioid of the minibrot.

I noticed several patterns.  For example, bulbs neighboring on the cardioid of the minibrot with a period n times that of the cardioid get their first spokes at the start of 2^(n-1) way symmetry.  Bulbs neighboring these bulbs with a period k times their period (k*n times the period of the cardioid of the minibrot) get their first spoke at the start of 2^((k - 1)*n - 1) way symmetry.  Whatever happens on one bulb that has a period k times that of of a larger neighboring bulb will happen on all bulbs neighboring the larger bulb with a period k times that of the larger bulb. I don't have a proof for any of these patterns.

Bulbs neighboring larger bulbs of the Mandelbrot set can each be associated with a reduced fraction.  For example, the main disk of the Mandelbrot set corresponds to 1/2, the bulb just above the cusp of the Mandelbrot with a period of 7 corresponds to 1/7 while the one below the cusp corresponds to 6/7, the bulb with a period of 13 just above the main disk corresponds to 6/13 while the one just below the main disk corresponds to 7/13.  This correspondence can be applied recursively, i.e. the bulb with a period of 6 neighboring the bulb with a period of 2 can be described as 1/2-->1/3

Likewise, there is a correspondence between the spokes and numbers between 0 and 1: the largest spoke on the needle corresponds to 1/2, the spoke on the 1/3 bulb corresponds to 1/4, the largest spoke on the 1/4 bulb corresponds to 1/8, the largest spoke on the    1/2--1/3 bulb corresponds to 3/8, while the one on 1/2-->2/3 corresponds to 5/8

I decided to ask how long of an interval each of the bulbs covered, and this is what I found: for the 1/k bulb, the upper bound of the interval will be 1/2^(k-1) + 1/2^(2k-1) + 1/2^(3k-1)...=2/((2^k)-1).  This sum corresponds to a sequence of spokes that approaches the left side of the 1/k bulb: the largest spoke on 1/k, then on bulb 1/k-->2/3, then 1/k-->3/4, then 1/k-->4/5, and so on.  The lower bound of the interval will be 1/2^k + 1/2^(2k) + 1/2^(3k)...=1/((2^k)-1).  This sum corresponds to the spokes on a sequence of bulbs approaching the right side of the bulb: the largest spoke on bulb 1/(k+1), then on 2/(2k+1), then 3/(3k+1) and so on.

After looking around, I found that everything I have been describing has already been independently discovered and appears to have been proven, but there is one implication of this that I can't find any information on: Since all bulbs of period k neighboring the main cardioid will have the same length, and there will be totient(k) such bulbs, this implies that the sum of totient(n)/((2^n)-1) from n=2 to infinity will be 1.  Can this sum be proven from what has already been proven about the structure of the mandelbrot set, are there any other proofs of this sum, or applications of it?

Comment: Hi Joseph, it's usually better on MathOverflow to put your actual question close to the top of the text, and then you can provide some of the motivation for why you were led to this question. Also, it's important to learn a little bit of LaTeX so that the math in your question can be displayed in readable form. For example, your question is how to prove the equality $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\phi(n)}{2^n-1}=1.$$ The way I displayed this is by putting the following text between double dollar signs: \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\phi(n)}{2^n-1}=1.

Comment: See the "Lambert series" discussion at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Generating_functions